# Declaring a variable if something is true

Tags: sql, variables, if-statement

I'm receiving an error message when i try to execute this code in order to set variables:

```
DECLARE
      @timenow DATETIME = GETDATE()
          ,@WEEKDAY nvarchar(10) = DATENAME(DW,GETDATE())   
IF DATENAME(DW,GETDATE()) = 'MONDAY'
DECLARE @Fecha_222 DATETIME SET @Fecha_222 = @timenow-3
ELSE 
SET @Fecha_222 = @timenow-1
```

I want to set variable @Fecha_222 to retreive the day of te day inmediatly before. If it's monday then give me the Friday date, If not..give me the day before.
I'm receiving error message saying Incorrect sintax near keyword else.
What it's wrong in the code ? I will really appreciate your help!! 
Many thanks in advance!

Marcos

Answer (score 1):

You had three problems:
1) You had the declaration in one half of an if referenced in the other.
2) You had multiple lines of SQL after an IF without using a BEGIN and END
3) This is more cosmetic, but could lead to logic issues. You declare @timenow and set it to GETDATE(), but in the IF, you are not referencing the variable. If you wanted to simulate the code for a different date, you'd have multiple places to fix it.

```
DECLARE
      @timenow DATETIME = GETDATE()
     ,@WEEKDAY nvarchar(10) = DATENAME(DW,GETDATE())   
     ,@Fecha_222 DATETIME

IF DATENAME(DW,@timenow) = 'MONDAY'
   SET @Fecha_222 = @timenow-3
ELSE 
   SET @Fecha_222 = @timenow-1
```

Comment: Excelent! it's working now! and thanks for the recomendations! really helpfully!

Answer (score 0):

Move the declaration outside of th eIF block:

```
DECLARE
      @timenow DATETIME = GETDATE()
          ,@WEEKDAY nvarchar(10) = DATENAME(DW,GETDATE())   

DECLARE @Fecha_222 DATETIME 

IF DATENAME(DW,GETDATE()) = 'MONDAY'
    SET @Fecha_222 = @timenow-3
ELSE 
    SET @Fecha_222 = @timenow-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because when it comes in else condition it can't find @Fecha_222 because you have declared it in if condition which is not executed. so you have to declare @Fecha_222 outside if-else.

```
DECLARE
      @timenow DATETIME = GETDATE(),
      @WEEKDAY nvarchar(10) = DATENAME(DW,GETDATE(),   
      @Fecha_222 DATETIME

IF DATENAME(DW,GETDATE()) = 'MONDAY'
   SET @Fecha_222 = @timenow-3

ELSE 
   SET @Fecha_222 = @timenow-1
```